# Don't click through button in subview

Tags: swift

On my viewcontoller i have placed an subview, on this subview is an button. The subview is default hidden and fades in on certain moments.

When the subview fades in and i push on the button i can interact with the elements behind the button but this is not what i want.

what i want is that You can't interact with the elements behind the button, only with the button itself. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the subview. This will cause it to "catch" touches (and, by default, do nothing with them).